# Fixes for "This class does not support SAAJ 1.3" do not work

Tags: java, maven, soap, saaj

I'm trying to send a soap request from a java method according to example but getting "This class does not support SAAJ 1.3".  Others have reported this error but the recommended fixes did not work for me.

What have I tried?

1. Added saaj-impl-1.3.jar and saaj-api-1.3.jar into maven
   dependencies.

> ```
> <dependency>  
> <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>     
> <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>     
> <version>1.3</version> 
> </dependency> 
>
> <dependency>  
> <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>     
> <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>    
> <version>1.3</version> 
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Added them into my java lib/ext folder
3. Added

`-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl`

to my JAVA_OPTIONS in startWebLogic.sh.  Stopped and restarted weblogic.

Added

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_3.SOAPMessageFactory1_3Impl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory","weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl");
```

To my code.  Nothing worked.  Still getting same message.  These frameworks are supposed to save you time.  Instead they do the opposite.  Getting ready to do it the old way unless someone has an idea?

Comment: Showing the POM would help.

Comment: I added them for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was no

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_3.SOAPMessageFactory1_3Impl");
```

By peaking inside the jar, I could see it should be

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl");
```

That worked.  Did not need the other property to be set.